# React is displaying my component multiple times on the webpage?

Tags: reactjs, components, rendering

I have tried to add a component onto my webpage and its showing multiple divs displaying the same component. Its stacked multiple divs containing this component giving me and endless scroll and a infinitely long webpage.

I only want this component/div to show onces on the page. Anyone know what I've done wrong?

The component in question is

Here's my code...

```
import styles from "./SearchCards.module.css";
import Select from "react-select";
import setOptions from "../data/sets";
import SpinnerOverride from "../utils/SpinnerOverride";
import SetOverview from "../components/SetOverview";

/**
 * The `SearchCards` component represents a page in my app
 * which allows the user to search for cards by their name
 * and filter them by their set.
 */

export default function Search() {
  // Track the `loading` state property of `SearchCards` page/component with the method `setLoading
  // this is true by default.
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  // Track the value of the `searchInput` state property with the method `setSearchInput` field
  // An empty string by default
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");

  // Track the value of the selected `set`state property of cards with method `setSet`
  // null by default
  const [set, setSet] = useState(null);

  // Track the `cards` state property that have been returned from the api with the `setCards` method
  // An empty array by default
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  // The base url for the api which will append extra info
  // to based on the users input/selections.
  const SEARCH_CARDS_BASE_URL = "https://api.pokemontcg.io/v2/cards";

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchCards() {
      // update the `loading` state to `true`
      setLoading(true);

      // Transform the text in the search input field to lowercase
      // and remove any leading and trailing whitespace
      const cleanSearchInput = searchInput.toLowerCase().trim();

      // Format the fetch url based on whether the search input
      // and set filter values.
      let url = `${SEARCH_CARDS_BASE_URL}?`;
      if (set && set.value !== "all") {
        // if `set` is not null, and the value is not 'all', then
        // the user must have manually set the `set` using the set
        // filter, so append it to the url
        url += `q=set.id:${set.value}`;

        if (cleanSearchInput === "") {
          // If the user has not entered any input into the search
          // input, display the first 50 cards from the api
          <SetOverview />;
        } else {
          // If the user has entered something in the search input, then
          // search for all cards with that name
          url += ` name:${cleanSearchInput}`;
        }
      }

      // Log out the final url which will be passed to the fetch
      // function -- for debugging purposes only.
      console.log(url);

      // Fetch the data from the API
      const resp = await fetch(url);

      // Parse the response into json
      const cards = await resp.json();

      // Update the `cards` state to be an array of card objects
      setCards(cards.data);

      // Wait 4 seconds before setting the `loading` state to false.
      // This gives react time to fully update the `cards` state.
      setTimeout(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      }, 2500);
    }

    // Call the `fetchCards` function
    fetchCards();

    // if either the `searchInput` or `set` values change
    // the `fetchCards` function will execute.
  }, [searchInput, set]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className={styles.header}>Search Pokemon</h1>

      <input
        className={styles.searchInput}
        type="text"
        value={searchInput}
        // When the text inside the search input field changes
        // update the value of the `searchInput` state
        onChange={(e) => setSearchInput(e.target.value)}
        placeholder={"e.g. Pikachu"}
      />

      <Select
        className={styles.setFilter}
        defaultValue={setOptions[0]}
        // When the filter option in the filter dropdown changes
        // update the the value of the `set` state
        onChange={(newSet) => setSet(newSet)}
        name="set"
        // `setOptions` is an array of objects, where each object
        // represents one set. See src/data/sets.js
        options={setOptions}
        classNamePrefix="select"
      />
      {loading ? (
        // If the `loading` state is true, display the loading spinner
        <SpinnerOverride />
      ) : !loading && cards.length === 0 ? (
        // If the `loading` state is false, and there are no cards
        // in the array, then tell the user that no cards have been
        // found
        <h2>No cards found</h2>
      ) : (
        // If the app is not loading, and there are cards in the
        // `cards` array, then render them out on the screen for the
        // user to see.
        <div className={styles.flexboxContainer}>
          {cards.map((card, idx) => {
            // Pass the data for each card returned from the
            // api into the `CardOverview` component which will
            // render the data (image, name, set, etc) to the screen
            return (
              <div key={idx}>
                <SetOverview />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: the component in question is SetOverview

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it was designed to do exactly what you describe:

```
  {cards.map((card, idx) => {
            // Pass the data for each card returned from the
            // api into the `CardOverview` component which will
            // render the data (image, name, set, etc) to the screen
            return (
              <div key={idx}>
                <SetOverview />
              </div>
            );
          })}
```

Here it loops over the `cards` array and returns `SetOverview` for each one. In your case, it will be repeated for as many "cards" that come back from the server.

We'd need to know what youre actually trying to do to help further.

If you want to render it alone, and not tie it to the cards array, just do this instead:

```
 <div className={styles.flexboxContainer}>
           <SetOverview />
        </div>
```

Comment: So before I made this component I had a component in its place that displays pokemon cards from an API, Im guessing I need to alter it so it doesn't think its still trying to do this

Comment: I edited my answer with a suggestion